# Compaing dates with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am comparing two Dates in column W and AA. 
The case is if Column AA > W, then it should print Nok.
If column AA <= W , then it should print OK.

I have my code working. but the Problem is  equal to condition is not satisfied.

For eg I have a date 01.09.2017 in column W and AA, According to the formula it should be Ok, but it prints NOK.

Could anyone tell me , what is wrong with the condition. I want it to do in VBA.

```
Sub Compare1()

    Dim i               As Long
    Dim lngLastRow      As Long
    Dim ws              As Worksheet            

    Set ws = Sheets("BW")    
    With ws            
        For i = 2 To 591
            If .Cells(i, 27).Value = "" Then            
                .Cells(i, 28).Value = "N/A"
            Else            
                If .Cells(i, 27).Value <= .Cells(i, 23).Value Then            
                    .Cells(i, 28).Value = "OK"
                    .Cells(i, 28).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)            
                Else                
                    .Cells(i, 28).Value = "NOK"              
                    .Cells(i, 28).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                End If            
            End If                
        Next i
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I prefer comparing dates with `DateDiff` function.

Comment: Your problem can be cause if your 2 dates contains hours and minutes. 
You need to format them and in case they contain hours and minutes you need to split them and the you can get rid of the hr and min.

Comment: @lonut how do i get rid of the hours and min

Comment: try `cdate(.Cells(i, 27).Value)` or even something like `cdate(replace(.Cells(i, 27).Value,".","/"))`

Comment: @Nathan_Sav still the Problem exist. I have time stamp in my column

Comment: @ShaiRado can you tell me how I can use that here?

Comment: Give me half an hour, I'm having lunch now

Comment: Sure. @ShaiRado I can wait

Comment: `format(.Cells(i, 27).Value,"dd/mm/yyyy")`  ???`format(replace(.Cells(i, 27).Value,".","/"),"dd/mm/yyyy")`  Can you show an example of some data in the post.

Comment: If you want to ignore the time portion of a date field, just use `Int` - i.e. `If Int(.Cells(i, 27).Value) <= Int(.Cells(i, 23).Value) Then`

Comment: Look up DateDiff. Or else crudely you could do int or fix functions.

Comment: @YowE3K Yes, this is in addition to my CDATE post earlier.

Comment: @YowE3K Thank you it works.

Comment: @Mikz if your date contains hr and minute(it should look like this mm/dd/yyyy hr:mm:ss) and if you are using an array to read them, you can use this statement: dim date() as string 
date()= Split(your_array, " ") and then the result only with the date will be date(0). In case you don't use array you can still replace the array statement with a string or with the statement you currently use cells(x,y).value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `DateDiff` function to get the Delta between 2 dates.

When putting "d" as the first parameter, you are checking the delta in days, so if both dates are the same, just the hourse ar different, the result will still be `0`.

To learn more about `DateDiff` function go to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Language-Reference-VBA/articles/datediff-function)

***Code***

```
Sub Compare1()

    Dim i               As Long
    Dim lngLastRow      As Long
    Dim ws              As Worksheet
    Dim DeltaDays       As Long

    Set ws = Sheets("BW")
    With ws
        For i = 2 To 591
            If .Cells(i, 27).Value = "" Then
                .Cells(i, 28).Value = "N/A"
            Else
                DeltaDays = DateDiff("d", .Cells(i, 27).Value, .Cells(i, 23).Value)
                If DeltaDays <= 0 Then
                    .Cells(i, 28).Value = "OK"
                    .Cells(i, 28).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
                Else
                    .Cells(i, 28).Value = "NOK"
                    .Cells(i, 28).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do it for you, your issue ,like the comments state, is that you are likely passing the time in your dates, the `Format` function will allow you to remove them, The reason for `On Error Resume Next` is that if the cells value is blank is will give the error `13 - Type Mismatch`

```
Sub Compare1()

    Dim i As Long, lngLastRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim FirstDate As Date, SecondDate As Date

    Set ws = Sheets("BW")

    With ws

        For i = 2 To 591

            On Error Resume Next
            FirstDate = Format(.Cells(i, "AA").Value, "dd/mm/yyyy")
            SecondDate = Format(.Cells(i, "W").Value, "dd/mm/yyyy")
            On Error GoTo 0

            If FirstDate = Empty Then
                .Cells(i, 28).Value = "N/A"
            Else
                If FirstDate <= SecondDate Then
                    .Cells(i, "AB").Value = "OK"
                    .Cells(i, "AB").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
                Else
                    .Cells(i, "AB").Value = "NOK"
                    .Cells(i, "AB").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                End If
            End If

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

You can also use the below instead of the `If` statement, I personally feel it is simpiler and clean but that is personal preference

```
Select Case FirstDate
    Case Is = ""
        .Cells(i, "AB").Value = "N/A"
    Case Is <= SecondDate
        .Cells(i, "AB").Value = "OK"
        .Cells(i, "AB").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
    Case Is > SecondDate
        .Cells(i, "AB").Value = "NOK"
        .Cells(i, "AB").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
End Select
```

Answer (score 0):

If your columns W and AA contain dates **with times**, the easiest fix is to just remove those times by taking the integral part of the date/time value.

So you can use:

```
If Int(.Cells(i, 27).Value) <= Int(.Cells(i, 23).Value) Then
```

---

Just be aware that this will be deciding that a date/time of, for instance, 10:00am on 28 June 2017 is less than or equal to 7:00am on the same date, which sounds like what you are trying to do - but it does raise the question of why the times are in the cells if they are just going to be ignored anyway.

Comment: because they from database, and it cant be ignored.

Comment: @Mikz If the data is from a database, and the designer of the database decided that it was important that the fields contain a specific time, it is probably wrong to treat 10:00am as being earlier than 7:00am, so your current code is probably working correctly.

Comment: currently it is working fine. Both the ideas are good, with datediff and INT